# Configure maven dependencies for Spring cloud

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-security

I want to create a Spring Cloud using `spring-cloud-starter-parent`. I tried this POM configuration:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Hoxton.SR6</version>
    </parent>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kaczmarzyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>specification-arg-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- This dependency is only used for the Topics API sample, which requires the Jackson JSON parser -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0-M1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Github [code](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/pom.xml):

In order to configure spring cloud project which dependencies I need to use and which I have to replace into the existing project?

Currently I get `Cannot resolve method 'authenticated' in 'RequestMatcherConfigurer'` which might be cause to wrong Maven dependencies.

I'm trying this configuration:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                    .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/revoke").permitAll()
                    .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, it is hard to say what is going on. Please post the relevant code. Also, [`RequestMatcherConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.RequestMatcherConfigurer.html) does not seem to have a method `authenticated(...)`.

Comment: I updated the post. But when I try to make a request to `/oauth/revoke` I get `    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"`

Comment: You are not using `authenticated()` in the code provided. Please keep the question consistent with your code.

Comment: Can you please propose answer how this configuration should be properly set?